# How to add javascript code to safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I create a safari extension , but I don't kown how to add javascript code to safari extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Safari extension is almost *entirely* Javascript. That's a bit of an oversimplification, but what kind of extension have you created if there's no Javascript? You can write as much or as little JS as you like in any [injected script](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW4) or in a [global HTML](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage/AddingaGlobalHTMLPage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH16-DontLinkElementID_29) file. The details of where/when/how to use each of these is [pretty well documented](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH1-SW1).

There's nothing particularly special about the nature of the Javascript that you can place in any of these files except that you do have access to a Safari-centric API. Otherwise, it's just the same old Javascript you'd write for the web with a few quirks of the framework itself. A lot of folks even include jQuery or other JS libraries to help, though they add more overhead than I'd recommend in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read this first.
[Safari Extension Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)